# Naming conflict between c library and c++ library

Tags: c, namespaces

I do not normally program in C++ and I am more comfortable in C.  I have a C library that I wrote and now I am trying to use it together with a specific function (a graph planarity testing function) in the Boost C++ Graph library.  In so doing, I am getting a compilation error which seems to involve a naming conflict between my part of my own c libraries linked list implementation and some far away link function in some directory in the bowls of my computer that is being called on by one of these Boost library functions:

```
    ./list.c:7:22: error: redefinition of 'link' as different kind of symbol
typedef struct node *link;
                     ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/unistd.h:464:6: note: previous definition is here
int      link(const char *, const char *);
         ^
In file included from boost_graph_test.cpp:15:
In file included from ./graph_dt.c:1:
```

How should I go about fixing this naming conflict (I would rather not change the code in my existing c library)?  I feel like some namespace thing should do the trick but unfortunately, I am not sure what exactly to do.

Comment: Changing your code will be much easier than changing boost.

Comment: @sweenish it's not boost, it's [posix](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/link.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `link` function is a standard system function used for creating hard links and symbolic links in the filesystem.  It's declared in `unistd.h` (which is used pretty commonly) and has been around since 4.3 BSD.  So you can't use this name for something else.

This means that, given this this is a C library, you'll have to rename your variable.

Comment: Thank you for the information.  I will probably just go with the renaming option however, I am not really sure how I would do the namespacing (since it is a c library).  Is there a way I can wrap the preprocessor call of my c++ file to the c library in a namespace somehow?

Comment: @l_frost Yes, since it is a C library, then your only option is to rename.

Answer (score 1):

Well:

```
typedef struct node *link;

/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/unistd.h:464:6: note: previous definition is here
```

- Here you define `link` as a type.

```
int      link(const char *, const char *);
         ^
In file included from boost_graph_test.cpp:15:
In file included from ./graph_dt.c:1:
```

- Here you are defining (probably not you, the system has a function called `link` to make a second link of a file.

You cannot have a type and a function with the same name.  The solution IMHO is to rename your type to something like

```
typedef struct node *link_t;
```

and *Voila!!!*

(**Note:** you will have to search for all occurences of type `link` in your sources and rename them also to `link_t`)

Comment: Thank you Luis -- I have now down just that and it's all running smooth as can be.